# Multilanguage in FilterConfig in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual, culture

I am making an asp.net MVC multi language website. 
I wrote this code to change the language according to the cookies which will be set from the user.

I wrote the code:

```
public class LocalizationAttribute : IActionFilter
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string lang = Cookies.CurrentLanguageCode;
            if (Validate.IsLanguage(lang))
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO: Redirect to Error Page
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("ERROR: Invalid language code '{0}'.", lang.ToLower()));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            }
        }
    }
```

in the filterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new LocalizationAttribute(), 0);
        }
```

and when I run the application I receive this error:

> The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following
>   filter interfaces: System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.

the code works fine, how to fix this error? 
thank you

Comment: this may help you.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/26677989/4323328

Comment: this link did not help